# notepad ++ Как добавить символ в конце определенных строк

Tags: notepad++

День добрый! Подскажите, есть некоторые строки которые начинаются с  команды "G00", в конце каждой такой строки мне нужно добавить "F 3000". Вопрос в том как это сделать не во всех подряд строках, а именно в тех что начинаются с "G00"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, используя регулярные выражения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо огромное!